# Case OWD is Private, then will Attachment will be Controll by Parent or will it be Private like Case?

Tags: apex

I have OWD for Case is Private. Payment1 and Payment2 has lookup relationship with Case. Even Payment1 and Payment2 OWD is private.

Scenarios:
Requestor will create a Case via Community Portal.

- Once case is submitted, Queue will become owner of the Case - Making Queue as  owner by Apex code.
- Original requestor will get READ access via APex Share object on Case, Payment-1 and Payment-2 object.

If Agent found submitted info needs update, then Agent will create a Task and allow user to give EDIT access only (via Apex Share) on this sections where needs correction (no edit access on whole case).

When Requestor got the EDIT access, on 1 sections, I have an OOTB attachment also, Requestor is able to save the Payment-1 records, but not the attachment object why ?

If Case OWD is Private, will Attachment be controlled by Parent? or Will it be Private like case and need to give access via Apex Share object as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment object is not a First class object. If user has access to the Case then that user can create, modify, even if delete an existing attachment related to a Case.

You do not need to write anything to provide access to the Attachment, irrespective of Case's OWD.

Refer: [Who Can See My Attached Files and Links?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_attachments.htm&type=5)

- If You Attach a File: On a record
- Who Can See It?: Anyone with sharing rights to the record
- Where Does it Appear?:

  1. Record detail page
  2. Your profile page
  3. Feed search results
  4. All Company or Company Highlights feed